# Can we check if the user who has logged in using the firebase auth, belongs to a particular node from the firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase, I am using the Auth and Realtime Database services, so in my database I have two nodes- "User" and "Owner",
[Database Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hBt4.png)

When the user registers using the auth, their data is put in either of these nodes (which is done using activities, there's a radio button for people to select if they are user or owner and proceed with the activity depending on their choice),
[Auth table snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSUfd.png)

What I want to implement now, is a way to determine if the person who logs in using the credentials from firebase auth, belongs to the "users" node or the "owners" node, as I am new to this, please provide the code or a way to manipulate my database to facilitate this determination.

Comment: Sounds like you should query the database to find the information you need.

Comment: add a string "user" or "owner" with data also when your app register someone no need to get node..:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your activity's onStart() method:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

mDatabase.getReference("Owners").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Map<String,Object> owners = (Map)snapshot.getValue();
            if(owners.containsKey(mUser.getUid())){
                //Owner code
            }
            else{
                //User code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
});
```

This is a way you can do it but it would be better if you rethink your database design to do it faster. Instead of having two nodes you could just add an attribute to the user (say 'role') to indicate his role instead of having two nodes seperately. Better have the user UID on the first level itself.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this helped me allot and it works for me, changing the database design with  a new attribute "role" wouldnt work for me as there are different sets of attributes for "Owners" and "Users", there are extra attributes for "Owners" which is non existent in "users"

Comment: I understand what you wanted. But the way I have shown is the only way you can do it and it causes a significant overhead as the number of owner child nodes increase. It would be better to add another node in your database as "Roles" and when the user is created add a value to his UID indicating his role. It would be easier to access this path from the DatabaseReference when logged in using the URL. I hope you get my point. Cheers!

Comment: yes sir, I thought you had mentioned in your answer that i need to add another attribute "roles",  i got confused with attribute and nodes, adding a new node "roles" makes a lot of sense, thank you so much sir !